# value match within a list

Tags: r, list, matching

I have a list such as created by this code:

```
lst <- list(c(c(1,2,3)), c(3,4,5))
names(lst) <- c("A","B")
```

and which looks like this:

```
> lst
$`A`
[1] 1 2 3

$B
[1] 3 4 5
```

How can I value match in a way that returns true or false for each list element? How can I then extract the names of the lists for which this is true. So in this example if I wish to value match "2" I would want to return

```
[1] TRUE, FALSE
```

and then I would like to return the name of the list where this is true so:

```
[1] "A"
```

If i was value matching 3 I would want:

```
[1] TRUE, TRUE
```

and

```
[1] "A", "B"
```

I can't find a way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
val = 3
names(lst)[sapply(lst, function(x) val %in% x)]

[1] "A" "B"
```

Explanation:

1. `sapply(lst, function(x) val %in% x))`: returns a vector of boolean values
2. `names`: get the names according to boolean values

Comment: `sapply` can be a convenient alternative to `unlist(lapply(...))`, or `vapply` if you want somewhat safer type strictness.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lst = list(A = c(c(1,2,3)), B = c(3,4,5))

searchValue = 2
z = sapply(lst, function(x){ searchValue%in%x })
```

Results:

```
> z
    A     B 
 TRUE FALSE 

> names(z)[z]
[1] "A"
```